# Blender 3.0, Grid is not showing, only at the bottom

Tags: vertices

I am an noob when it comes to blender and I am following (like most noobs I guess) the donut tutorial on YT from Blenderguru,

Now I made it through to the icing and now it is time to shape it and when I go to edit mode I only see dots at the bottom of it [image: Blender Donut]

How can I fix this, I have been searching all over the net but nothing found so far...

Thank you for helping out.

Dave

Comment: You need to click on the "On Cage"  button for the Solidify modifier. Or you can do this even for the Subdivision modifier, this way it also turns on for the Solidify modifier because of their order.

https://i.imgur.com/s4Eo0xK.png

Comment: Thanks that worked...